Parcheesi Board Game Rules Question Double 5’s
2 pawns on a start space. 2 pawns still at home waiting to enter. Player rolls double 5’s. What moves can he make and does he get to roll again?

You can move one piece forward five and then bring a piece from home to the start space. Or you can move the two pieces five each. Or move one five and then move the same piece another five.
Regardless, you get to roll again (unless you couldn't move because the space 5 ahead is blocked; although Milton Bradley rules lack this restriction).
Parker Brothers rules
